# MetaWear : CLI application on MACOSX

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am attempting to follow the MetaWear guide on starting a sample application, located h[ere](https://mbientlab.com/iosdocs/latest/project_setup.html) . The problem that I am quickly running into is that I am getting unexpected crashes. Here is how my code is structured

[image]:

[image]

Lastly, my Podfile contains the following:

```
platform :osx, '10.12.6'

target 'meta-wear' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'MetaWear', '~> 2.9'
end
```

When I run the application, I get a Thread exception as follows on line 5 of the first image:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

While I am certainly a new Swift developer ( noob ), I have no idea why I am unable to reproduce their guide.

Xcode: 9.0
macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 ( This is where I want to run this command line application )

**Update after adding an infinite loop**

I updated the main.swift class to ahve the following:

```
import Foundation

let runLoop = RunLoop.current;
let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture;

print("### we are in the create");
let starter = MetaWearStarter();
print("### we are after the create");

while (runLoop.run(mode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode, before:    distantFuture)){
    print("### listening for a metawear device");
}
```

I created a class called MetaWearStarter.swift as follows:

```
import Foundation

import MetaWear

class MetaWearStarter : NSObject {

    override init() {
        super.init();
        print("### we are in the init");
        startConnection();
    }

    func startConnection() {
        print("##### connection call was made");
        let manager = MBLMetaWearManager.shared();
        maanger.startScanForMetaWears() { array in
        print("### connection scan was complete")    
        // Hooray! We found a MetaWear board, so stop scanning for more
            MBLMetaWearManager.shared().stopScan()
            // Connect to the board we found
            if let device = array.first {
                device.connectAsync().success() { _ in
                    print("#### we connected to a device");
                    }.failure() { error in
                        print("### unable to connect");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get the previous error on this line:

```
let manager = MBLMetaWearManager.shared();
```

And my output never makes it past that line:

```
### we are in the create
### we are in the init
##### connection call was made
```

Comment: To perform an asynchronous task in a CLI you need at least a run loop and strictly spoken a CLI is not an application per se.

Comment: @vadian I added an infinite loop, but still get the same issue, even on the same line . hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

An infinite loop to keep the runloop running is not a good habit.

Add a completion handler to your class and stop the runloop on completion.

The usual way to handle the run loop in a CLI is this:

```
import Foundation
import MetaWear

class MetaWearStarter  {

    let manager = MBLMetaWearManager.shared()

    func startConnection(completion: @escaping (String)->()) {
        print("##### connection call was made");
        manager.startScanForMetaWears() { array in
            print("### connection scan was complete")
            // Hooray! We found a MetaWear board, so stop scanning for more
            manager.stopScan()
            // Connect to the board we found
            if let device = array.first {
                device.connectAsync().success() { _ in
                    completion("#### we connected to a device")
                    }.failure() { error in
                        completion("### unable to connect, error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else {
                completion("#### no device found")
            }
        }
    }
}

let starter = MetaWearStarter()
let runLoop = RunLoop.current
starter.startConnection { (result) in
    print(result)
    CFRunLoopStop(runLoop.getCFRunLoop())
}

runLoop.run()
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: thanks  for that explanation vadian. I'll have to update my other cli apps to run a similar loop. && even when I use your code, I get the same exact error. I am guessing that you are  not getting any issues?

Comment: I'm not using that particular pod. From the perspective to run an asynchronous task in a CLI the code is supposed to work.

Comment: thanks vadian. if you use the framework in the future, and solve the problem before I do, let me know. thanks for your help.